# Navigation between pages in blackberry webworks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I want to know how to handle navigation between html pages. When I am using

```
window.location.href = "Screen1.html";
```

I am able to load the new page, but when I click the back button, the application gets terminated. How can I handle this?

In native java blackberry, the screen will be on stack, so how it be done in webworks?

Answer (score 1):

i think the better way is to use HTML url 
`<a href="Screen1.html" >` 
at the second page when you click on back button it will take you to the previews screen "as the normal browser do"